# How to center the middle widget area in a three "column" setup

Tags: css

In modifying my wordpress theme, I went from a content/sidebar layout to a full width one. In the content portion there were two "widget areas" home-middle-left (floated left) and home-middle-right (floated right). When I went full width I added a third widget area called home-far right.

I can't figure out how to make the middle widget area be centered and equidistant from the other two. As it stands right now, it's stuck to the one on  the right.

http://signaturehouston.com

Thanks

P.S Sorry if my description isn't technically correct - I'm new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Give margin to your Div

try adding this :

```
.home-middle-right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 35px;  /*ADD THIS*/
}
```

You can change the margin as per your layout need

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your middle widget its own class because you are using the same class for the middle and right widget divs. Say you call it:

```
<div class="home-middle widget-area">
```

The css:

```
.home-middle {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 332px;
}
```

The problem is you are using the same class as the widget on the left so it floats right. And the `margin: 0 auto;` will center it at all times, dynamically.